# Question regarding conditional probability

Tags: probability

I'm doing a programming project but I'm having trouble with the probability part of it. I have a setup as such.

```
 C
/ \ 
A  B
```

I am given P(C), P(A|C), P(B|C). 
I need to find P(C|A,B) so I need help breaking down this P(C|A,B) into an equation which contains the givens so that I am able to calculate this probablity.

Comment: are you trying the find the probability of $C$ happening given that $A$ and $B$ happend?

Comment: There isn't enough information here to determine the value $P(C \mid A, B)$.  You have enough to determine $P(C), P(A, C)$, and $P(B, C)$; if you were to assume conditional independence of $A$ and $B$ given $C$, you could also have $P(A, B, C)$.  But there isn't enough there to determine $P(A, B)$, which you need.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram you provided usually indicates that $A$ and $B$ are *conditionally independent* given $C$.   This tells us that:

$$\mathsf P(C\mid A, B) = \frac{\mathsf P(A\mid C)\;\mathsf P(B\mid C)\;\mathsf P(C)}{\mathsf P(A,B)}$$

You have the three factors in the numerator, but are missing the joint probability in the denominator.   More information is required; such as the conditionals when $C$ does not happen.

$$\mathsf P(A,B) = \mathsf P(A\mid C)\;\mathsf P(B\mid C)\;\mathsf P(C)+\mathsf P(A\mid C^\complement)\;\mathsf P(B\mid C^\complement)\;\mathsf P(C^\complement)$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll be able to figure it out from here.